# Load Activity with dynamic view and content in Android

Tags: android, json, dynamic, view, android-activity

I am very new to Android development and I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following goal:

I want to have a main menu that holds several buttons. Each of those buttons should load a second Activity and pass some data to this Activity.

The Secondary Activity should display a tabbar that switches between three different views or activities:
1. A static view created for each element (button on main menu)
2. An image gallery with a set of images associated with that element
3. Another page with dynamic content like a map and images.

My thought: Create a json file for each element and pass the name of that file to the Secondary Activity with could then create the views using that data.

Problem: Can you store the name of a layout.xml file as a string and then load it?

So what would be the best Practice to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the information of which layout/which views you want to display in the second activity as an extra on the intent used to start the activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("layout_identifier", 5);
startActivity(i);
```

Then extract this information in the receiving activity onCreate():

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int layout = b.getInt("layout_identifier", 0);
switch (layout) {
case 5:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_layout5);
    break;
```

Note that the datatype passed does not necessarily have to be int, you can pass all primitives, strings and a third option called Parcelable (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) which can be thought of as a container for objects.

Comment: thanks. Would it still make sense to pass a json file name. I'm afraid if I don't outsource this data somehow, my FirstActivity.java is going to be pretty messy. Whats your thought on that?

Comment: Doing it in JSON might be a bit overkill, but that kind of depends on the content that needs to be passed to the second activity. I would have to know more to be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Example Data: 1. The name of View 2. An array with maybe 10 image names 3. An Array with geolocations and a few urls. If I have to write all that in one Activity about 12 times this might get cluttered. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you should pass lists, or create a container class for these elements, and then loop over these lists/containers in the second activity?